# wordpress переключение css стилей на лету с сохранением выбора

Tags: wordpress, css

Добрый день!

Стоит задача, разработать версию для слабовидящих людей на wordpress 4.3.1
Должна быть панель, где можно выбрать размеры шрифтов и оформление сайты.
Взял такой код для реализации:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" type="text/css"  />
```

/css/sp-A1.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="sp-A1" />
/css/sp-A2.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="sp-A2" />
/css/sp-A3.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="sp-A3" />
function switchStyleSheet(title, media) {
    if (typeof media == "undefined" || media == "") {
        media = ".*";
    }

```
var mediaPattern = new RegExp("(^|,)\s*" + media + "\s*(,|$)");

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var rel = links[i].getAttribute("rel");
    var linkTitle = links[i].getAttribute("title");

    if (/(^| )stylesheet( |$)/.test(rel) && linkTitle != null && linkTitle != "") {
        var styleMedia = links[i].getAttribute("media");
        if (styleMedia == null || styleMedia == "" || styleMedia == "all" || mediaPattern.test(styleMedia)) {
            links[i].disabled = true;
            links[i].rel = "alternate stylesheet";

            if (linkTitle == title) {
                links[i].disabled = false;
                links[i].rel = "stylesheet"
            }
        }
    }
}

document.cookie = "stylesheet=" + title;
```

}

Добавил его в файл-шапки сайта. + добавил ссылки на переключение:

```
<a href="#" onclick="switchStyleSheet('sp-A1')" class="sp-a1">A1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="switchStyleSheet('sp-A2')" class="sp-a2">A2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="switchStyleSheet('sp-A3')" class="sp-a3">A3</a>
```

Скрипт работает отлично - стили переключает, только при переходах на другие страницы сбрасывает стили на поумолчанию.

По идее вот эта строчка document.cookie = "stylesheet=" + title; должна записывать в куки выбор и сохранять его. Но стили все равно слетают.
[Разрабатываемый сайт](http://gutocso3.ru/)
Скрипт взял [отсюда](http://www.jstoolbox.com/2008/04/05/sozdanie-pereklyuchatelya-stilej/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Куки вы сохраняете, но не проверяете, что в них записано, нужно под функцией добавить проверку

```js
var str = document.cookie;
if (str.indexOf('stylesheet')!==-1) {
 switchStyleSheet(str.substring(11));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за скорый ответ. Добавил этот код сразу после закрывающей скобки предыдущей функции: function switchStyleSheet(title, media). Проверил, не срабатывает все равно. Я не очень спец в js)

Comment: @КириллКулаков Прошу прощения, пропустил кавычки) Я поправил код, попробуйте

Comment: Неа.) Может он в куки не записывает? Можно как-то посмотреть что он в куки записал? Или вордпрес как-то что-то скидывает при обновлении страницы?

Comment: @КириллКулаков, странно, у меня работает) WP никакого отношения не имеет к куки, созданными JS-ом. Попробуйте удалить куки и загрузить страницу заново, а потом проводить тестирование

Comment: Заработал! :))) Спасибо выручили! А как теперь на стандартный стиль вернуть? (: Точнее как сделать так чтоб была кнопка: включить добавить css класс display: visible; к блоку с меню выбора стиля, а когда нажимаешь еще раз на эту кнопку, то добавлялся класс css display: none; и возвращался стиль по умолчанию у сайта?

Comment: Сранно, как-то работает, то получается то нет. То запомнит одну страницу, то нет.

Comment: @КириллКулаков Как вариант к `link` со стандартным стилем добавить атрибут `title="sp-A0"` и ссылку на включение стандартного стиля `<a href="#" onclick="switchStyleSheet('sp-A0')" class="sp-a0">Стандартный стиль</a>`. Это быстрое решение, для более масштабируемого подхода необходимо попробовать иначе, например, добавлять к `a` атрибут `data-current` и писать туда соответствие текущего стиля true или fasle, но это уже совсем другая история... Попробуйте быстрое решение

Comment: Попробую, спасибо. Сейчас, протестировал еще раз. Стиль начал запоминать на конкретной странице, и при обновлении страницы опять возвращает дефолтный.( Пользуюсь Chrome 46. На IE10 такая же беда. Может есть какие-то альтернативные пути решения той же задачи?